# SpriteKit where to load texture atlases for thousands of sprites

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios7, sprite-kit

In my game I have thousands of "tile" nodes which make up a game map (think simcity), I am wondering what the most frame-rate/memory efficient route for texturing and animating each node would be? There a a handful of unique tile "types" which each have their own texture atlas / animations, so making sure textures are being reused when possible is key.

All my `tile` nodes are children of a single `map` node, should the map node handle recognising a tile type and loading the necessary atlas & animations (e.g. by loading texture & atlas names from a plist?)

Alternatively, each tile type is a certain subclass. Would it be better for each SKSpriteNode tile to handle their own sprite atlas loading e.g. `[tileInstance texturise];` (how does sprite kit handle this? would this method result in the same texture atlas being loaded into memory for each instance of a certain tile type?)

I have been scrounging the docs for a deeper explanation of atlases and texture reusage but I  don't know what the typical procedure is for a scenario like this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Memory** first: there won't be any noticeable difference. You have to load the tile's textures, textures will account for at least 99% of the memory of the Map+Tiles and that's that.

Texture reuse: textures are being reused/cached automatically. Two sprites using the same texture will reference the same texture rather than each having its own copy of the texture.

**Framerate/Batching:** this is all about batching properly. Sprite Kit approaches batching children of a node by rendering them in the order they are added to the children array. As long as the next child node uses the same texture as the previous one, they will all be batched into one draw call. Possibly the worst thing you could do is to add a sprite, a label, a sprite, a label and so on. You'll want to add as many sprites using the same texture in consecutive order as is possible.

**Atlas Usage**: here's where you can win the most. Commonly developers try to categorize their atlases, which is the wrong way to go about it. Instead of creating one atlas per tile (and its animations), you'll want to create as few texture atlases as possible, each containing as many tiles as possible. On all iOS 7 devices a texture atlas can be 2048x2048 and with the exception of iPhone 4 and iPad 1 all other devices can use textures with up to 4096x4096 pixels.

There are exceptions to this rule, say if you have such a large amount of textures that you can't possibly load them all at once into memory on all devices. In that case use your best judgement to find a good compromise on memory usage vs batching efficiency. For example one solution might be to create one or two texture atlases per each unique scene or rather "scenery" even if that means duplicating some tiles in other texture atlases for another scene. If you have tiles that almost always appear in any scenery it would make sense to put those in a "shared" atlas.

As for **subclassing** tiles, I'm a strong proponent to avoid subclassing node classes. Especially if the main reason to subclass them is to merely change which texture they are using/animating. A sprite already is a container of a texture, so you can as well change the sprite texture and animate it from the outside.

To add data or additional code to a node you can peruse its userData property by creating your own NSMutableDictionary and adding any object you need to it. A typical **component-based** approach would go like this:

```
SKSpriteNode* sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteWithWhatever..];
[self addChild:sprite];

// create the controller object
sprite.userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
MyTileController* controller = [MyTileController controllerWithSprite:sprite];
[sprite.userData setObject: forKey:@"controller"];
```

This controller object then performs any custom code needed for your tiles. It could be animating the tile and whatever else. The only important bit is to make the reference to the owning node (here: sprite) a weak reference:

```
@interface MySpriteController
@property (weak) sprite; // weak is important to avoid retain cycle!
@end
```

Because the sprite retains the dictionary. The dictionary retains the controller. If the controller would retain the sprite, the sprite couldn't deallocate because there would still be a retaining reference to it - hence it will continue to retain the dictionary which retains the controller which retains the sprite.

The advantages of using a component-based approach (also favored by and implemented in [Kobold Kit](http://koboldkit.com)):

- If properly engineered, works with any or multiple nodes. If what if some day you want a label, effect, shape node tile?
- You don't need a subclass for every tile. Some tiles may be simple static sprites. So use simple static SKSpriteNode for those.
- It lets you start/stop or add/remove individual aspects as needed. Even on tiles you didn't initially expect to have or need a certain aspect.
- Components allow you to build a repertoire of functionality you're going to need often and possibly even in other projects.
- Components make for better architecture. A classical OOP design mistake is to have Player and Enemy classes, then realize both need to be able to shoot arrows and equip armor. So you [move the code to the root GameObject class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), making the code available to all subclasses. With components you simply have an equipment and a shooting component add to those objects that need it.
- The great benefit of component-based design is that you start developing individual aspects separately from other things, so they can be reused and added as needed. You'll almost naturally write better code because you approach things with a different mindset.
- And from my own experience, once you modularize a game into components you get far fewer bugs and they're easier to solve because you don't have to look at or consider other component's code - unless used by a component but even then when one component triggers another you have a clear boundary, ie is the passed value still correct when the other component takes over? If not, the bug must be in the first component.

This is a [good introduction on component-based design](http://entropyinteractive.com/2011/02/game-engine-design-component-based-entities/). The hybrid approach is certainly the way to go. Here are [more resources on component based design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901251/component-based-game-engine-design) but I strongly advice against straying from the path and looking into FRP as the "accepted answer's author" suggests - FRP is an interesting concept but has no real world application (yet) in game development.

Comment: Good detailed answer overall. Expanding on the bit about **batching**: if you set `ignoresSiblingOrder` to `YES` on your SKView, you don't need to worry so much about the order of children -- Sprite Kit will automatically sort them for efficient drawing (e.g. all sprites from the same texture atlas in one draw call). And on **atlases**: with `ignoresSiblingOrder` in mind, if you have too many/large textures for one atlas, it can help to use the node hierarchy to organize your scene into "layers" that can each be one draw call and one atlas (e.g. world vs HUD).

Comment: Btw, this line should have an object: `[sprite.userData setObject: forKey:@"controller"];`. Should be `[sprite.userData setObject:controller forKey:@"controller"];`