# Why in Unity3d Transform is a separate entity from GameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Every GameObject has Transform, and only one. Every Transform can only be created attached to a GameObject. Hierarchy is realized through Transform, but GameObject relies heavily on it.

Is there a reason about why they are different entities and not the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

[Component's](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component.html) and [GameObject's](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) are inherited types of a base class called [Object](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.html). Component's can only exist and be attached to Objects.

A [Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.html) is an inherited type of [Component](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component.html). All [GameObject's](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) must have a Transform Component attached to them. The reason being:

> Every object in a scene has a Transform. It's used to store and
>   manipulate the position, rotation and scale of the object. Every
>   Transform can have a parent, which allows you to apply position,
>   rotation and scale hierarchically. This is the hierarchy seen in the
>   Hierarchy pane.

If you asking **why** such an architecture is in place, you may find that this sort of discussion will be found debated in more than a few articles and books. I once asked this question myself and I found the following Stack Overflow answer to best answer it [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901251/component-based-game-engine-design).

Comment: Your answer explains how things are. But that wasn't my question. I was interested _why_ they are this way. Why did Unity engineers design it to be so?

Comment: Edited my answer to provide you a link to another StackOverflow QnA that I think will provide you your answer.

Comment: I'm familiar with component-based design, and I used decorator-like behaviors in projects before Unity; however, in this design pattern it still doesn't make sense to make the behavior which is always present on an object a separate decorator.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a relevant link that may better answer your question.